# how to fetch database value in ajax each 5 seconds

Tags: php, ajax, model-view-controller

I created a function to sum all the database records using MVC. Now I need to fetch those values each 5 seconds. The values are updated all the time but I couldn't fetch the latest value (the updated value), only the value when the page is loaded. Just to finish: I need to use an external file to get the sum.

```
    function TotalCosern(){

        $GetValores = $this->db->select("SELECT cosern FROM planilha");

        $acc = array_shift($GetValores);
        foreach ($GetValores as $val) {
            foreach ($val as $key => $val) {
                $acc[$key] += $val;
            }
        }
        return $acc;
        print_r($acc)//print the sum

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Put your ajax call in a function and use setInterval to execute that function every 5 seconds and append the response in your content div.

```
(function polling() {
  $.post('total.php', function(data) {
  $('#content').append(data);
  setTimeout(polling, 1000);
  });
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [setInterval](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp) function.
Example (using [get](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/) to make the ajax call):

```
function fetchData() {

  //change to your url
  $.get('/someurl/TotalCosern', function(data) {

    //refresh the sum content (or other container that you are using)
    $('#sum').html(data);
  })
}

//when the page is loaded, do the polling
$(document).ready(function () {

  //the time here is in milliseconds
  setInterval(fetchData, 5000);
})
```